# Websocket (WSS) migrate connection issue - from apache to Nginx

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, websocket

I am trying to migrate Apache websocket on windows to Nginx websocket on Ubuntu.

It works on commercial browsers (Chrome, Firefox) but I on mobile apps it reports an error:

`Failed websocket opening handshake was canceled`

I was searching a lot of that error but I am sure that it's a general error, not an specific error.

**Nginx configuration (works on browsers not on mobiles)**

```
server 
{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ws.example.com;
    root /var/www;
    ssl on;
    ssl_verify_client off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA;
    access_log /var/log/wss-access-ssl1.log;
    error_log /var/log/wss-error-ssl1.log;

   location /websocket 
   {
         access_log off;
         proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
         proxy_read_timeout 86400; # neccessary to avoid websocket timeout disconnect
         proxy_redirect off;
         satisfy any;
    }
}
```

**Apache configuration (works good on mobile and browsers)**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin email@email.es
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache/htdocs"
    ServerName ws.example.com   
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache/apache/conf/ssl/__cert_com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache/apache/conf/ssl/server.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "c:/Apache/apache/conf/ssl/__cert_com.ca-bundle"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
<Directory "c:/Apache/htdocs"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In the Apache configuration I added `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` I tried thaton Nginx, too but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a `map{}`, as documented [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html)? Nginx should not return 200.  Start with only proxy headers listed in the manual.

Comment: @Deadooshka I tried bro but not works... =(